# python 3: try except not working to check isalpha function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check that what's entered at the input function is all alpha characters. Basically I want to ensure numbers are not entered. However when I type a number such as 4 nothing happens. I don't even see an exception error. Also if i type anything besides "take honey" or "open door" it doesn't start the bear_room function. Haaalp. Thanks in advance!

```
def bear_room():
    print("there's a bear here")
    print("the bear has a bunch of honey")
    print("the fat bear is front of another door")
    print("how are you going to move the bear?")

    choice = str(input("(Taunt bear, take honey, open door?: "))
    try:
        if choice.isalnum() == False:
            if choice == "take honey":
                print("the bear looks at you then slaps your face off")
            elif choice == "open door":
                print("get the hell out")
        else: 
            bear_room()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        print("numbers are not accepted")
        bear_room()

bear_room()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to trigger an exception because code-wise it's perfectly legitimate to enter a number. It will check choice.isalnum(), it will be True for a number, and then bear_room() will be recursively called. You want the else part to contain the printing that you've got in the exception, then just get rid of the exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.

First, don't cast your input to an `str`. It is already coming in as a string from `input`.

Second, is that you will never raise an exception with how you are looking to catch the exception you are looking to catch, because your input is outside the try/except. Not only that, but you will not raise an exception if you enter something like `abcd1234`. That is still a valid string.

Bonus problem you have. Never catch an open `Exception`. Always be explicit with what kind of exception you want to catch. However, you don't need to do a try/except here. Instead, just check if you have valid entries and proceed with your logic.

Simply, remove your try/except and even your `isalnum` check, and just check if the string entered matches what you are looking for. If it does not, output some kind of error message:

```
def bear_room():
    print("there's a bear here")
    print("the bear has a bunch of honey")
    print("the fat bear is front of another door")
    print("how are you going to move the bear?")

    choice = input("(Taunt bear, take honey, open door?: ")
    if choice == "take honey":
        print("the bear looks at you then slaps your face off")
    elif choice == "open door":
        print("get the hell out")
    else:
        print("Invalid entry")
        bear_room()

bear_room()
```

Comment: Thanks- I over thought the process.